# Find documents by nested ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to identify correct syntax to retrieve articles by author with nested id `(author.id)`. Throws SyntaxError, can't find solution.

My route:

```
  router.get('/articles/authors/:id', function(req, res){

      Article.find( {author.id: req.params.id} ).sort( {createdAt: -1} ).exec(function(err, articles){
        if(err){
           console.log(err);
           return req.flash('error', 'Unable to find author.');
        } else {
           console.log(articles);
           res.render('authors/', {
              articles: articles,
              pagetitle: 'Articles by '
           });
        }
     });
  });
```

The author portion of my articleSchema is this:

```
   author:
   {
      id:
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"    
      },
      username: String, 
      name: String      
   },
```

If anyone can see my error(s), I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose nested paths in quotes. See [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/) which says:

> To specify a query condition on fields in an embedded/nested document, use the dot notation ("field.nestedField").

So your code

```
Article.find( {author.id: req.params.id} )
```

should be replaced with

```
Article.find( {"author.id": req.params.id} )
```

Comment: Brilliant! While trying to figure this out I put quotes around both, but that didn't work. Thanks so much Benjamin for taking the time to reply. Thanks also for the quote above. PS. Thanks for the link because I was searching Mongoose instead of Mongodb.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!